# How to use opencv in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, opencv

I have recently built an image recognition program in python using `opencv`.
Now i want to deploy it to the web. One option is to use `reactjs` as the front-end part and possibly install an available script `opencv.js` using `*npm*`.
But following the example code from `*npmjs*` i'm faced with this exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

throwed in this function:

```
cv.Matrix.prototype.detectObject = function () {...}
```

What is causing this? And how can i use opencv on the browser?

**Update**

This is how i imported **cv** (just by guessing, as the documentation doesn't show how to import).

```
import cv from opencv
```

But since the compiler didn't complain specifically about the import i assumed it must be correct

Comment: You need to show us more of your code. It probably has to do with the way you imported opencv.

Comment: @paulsbecks yes it can be. I've just updated the post to show the import

Comment: Alright so this happens some times. What I do is print cv to take a look at the object. If it actually has a property Matrix. But if I am right you should be able to import cv like: `const cv = require('opencv')` and it should work.